# Hartl Ruby on Rails tutorial Chapter 11 test issue: error message filling up console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have finished the chapter on Micropost Images. The issue comes after section 11.4, and when I run `bundle exec rake test` I get 7 errors. My console prints the following line all the way to the top of my console:

```
app/models/micropost.rb:13:in `picture_size'
app/models/micropost.rb:13:in `picture_size'
app/models/micropost.rb:13:in `picture_size'
app/models/micropost.rb:13:in `picture_size'
app/models/micropost.rb:13:in `picture_size'
app/models/micropost.rb:13:in `picture_size'
app/models/micropost.rb:13:in `picture_size'
app/models/micropost.rb:13:in `picture_size'
app/models/micropost.rb:13:in `picture_size'
app/models/micropost.rb:13:in `picture_size'
```

You get the idea. This is a headache because I can't even go through the console and figure out what I did wrong or how to fix it. In case it's relevant, below is the code for app/models/micropost.rb

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validate :picture_size

  private

  # Validates the size
    def picture_size
        if picture_size > 5.megabytes
            errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5MB")
        end
    end
end
```

My question is how can I stop `app/models/micropost.rb:13:in`picture_size'` from printing out ad nauseum and filling up my console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `picture_size` method is recursive, creating an infinite loop - it calls itself, which it will do infinitely.

The `if picture_size > 5.megabytes` is the culprit, which calls the method it is defined in. If that line is correct, then you should rename the actual validation method, for example, `validate :picture_under_size_limit` and `def picture_under_size_limit`.

Comment: I actually just found out what it is, in the book he writes "validate :picture_size" whereas it should be "validates". Typo error my noob-self didn't process.

Comment: @LesPaul no, it's not a typo. `validate` is used for custom validation methods, like the one you've written.

Comment: Then why when I changed it to "validates" did I get rid of all those errors?

Comment: Because the `picture_size` method you've defined is now no longer being called, and your validation isn't being run.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it was recursive and was causing that error. Thank you. Also, the code within the picture_size method should have been picture.size

Answer (score 0):

```
if picture_size > 5.megabytes
```

should be

```
if picture.size > 5.megabytes
```

Note the `.` instead of the `_`

Just made that mistake myself.